# IAsyncAuthorizationFilter is executed after redirect to login page

Tags: basic-authentication, asp.net-apicontroller, asp.net-core-5.0

I've migrated an ASP.NET Core MVC 2.2 web application to ASP.NET Core 5 MVC. I'm using an `IAsyncAuthorizationFilter` (global filter) to do `BasicAuthentication` for my API controllers.

In 2.2 this was working fine. With 5.0 (and I think also 3.1), I get the default login page when calling the `ApiController` because the `AuthorizationFilter` gets executed after the Identity framework is doing the redirect to the login page because of the `Authorize` attribute placed on the controller. The filter is registered as global filter in the `ConfigureServices` method.

I was able to reproduce the behavior by creating a new ASP.NET Core 5 web application with Identity (individual user account). Then I created an `ApiController` and a dummy `IAsyncAuthorizationFilter` that checks for the request path.

When I call the `ApiController` URL at `https://localhost:xxx/api/data/get` with Postman, the content of the login page is returned. As far as I know auth filter are executed first in the request pipeline in order to handle authorization.

But in that scenario I have no change to do that because the `Authorize` attribute on the controller causes the auth framework to request the login credentials via the login page. Was there a change from version 2.2 to 3.x/5.0 ?

Here are the code snippets.

Dummy filter:

```cs
public class ApiBasicAuthorizationFilter : IAsyncAuthorizationFilter
{
     public async Task OnAuthorizationAsync(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
     {
         // execute only when the api route is called
         // error: the route here is /Account/Login because OnAuthorizeAsync is executed after the Redirect
         if (context.HttpContext.Request.Path.Value.Contains("/api"))
         {
             var identity = new ClaimsIdentity("identity");
             identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "user1"));
             identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "user1"));
             var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
             context.HttpContext.User = principal;
         }
     }
}
```

Filter registration

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

    services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true).AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

    services.AddControllersWithViews(options => 
    {
        options.Filters.Add<ApiBasicAuthorizationFilter>();
    });
}
```

ApiController:

```cs
[ApiController]
[Route("api/data")]
[Authorize]
public class DataController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("get")]
    public async Task<string> GetData()
    {
        return "TEST";
    }
}
```

Comment: In 2.2, the asp.net core is authorized through  AuthorizationFilter, but from 3.x, it is authorized through middleware. Although it is still feasible through the filter.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I solved it by removing the registration as global filter, removed the Authorized attribute from the controller und replaced it with a custom attribute that implements IAsyncAuthorizationFilter

Comment: Ok, you are welcome.